# Parameters to pass to docker run automatically on startup

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run the following to docker run upon its invocation. For example, I need to specify this all the time I run docker

```
docker run -m 384m --cpu-shares 512 --read-only
```

Instead I'm trying to create bash script named docker-run.sh with the following contents

```
docker run -m 384m --cpu-shares 512 $@
```

So I need to specify

```
docker-run.sh -i -d --name rabbit2 -p 172.17.0.1:17235:80 -t centos7:v2
```

However, my session gets stuck after running this and I have to wait until my SSH session times out to login back to my system. 
How are other users doing it?

Comment: hum you are starting the container in foreground, try to use "-d" to start without output.

Comment: Aren't you having a problem in the parameters ? Why are you using the docker ip (172.17.0.1) when you're mapping ports ?

Comment: I'm only forcing it to listen on a docker IP rather than 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @opHASnoNAME I didn't understand what you mentioned. I start my docker using -i -d (see 3rd linecode on question)